# Regex: match word (but delete commas after OR before)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tried to delete an item from a string divided with commas:

`var str="this,is,unwanted,a,test";`

- if I do a simple `str.replace('unwanted','');` I end up with 2 commas
- if I do a more complex `str.replace('unwanted','').replace(',,','');`
  It might work

But the problem comes when the `str` is like this:

`var str="unwanted,this,is,a,test"; // or "...,unwanted"`

However, I could do a 'if char at [0 or str.length] == comma', then remove it

**But I really think this is not the way to go, it is absurd I need to do 2 replaces and 2 ifs to achieve what I want**

I have heard that regex can do powerful stuff, but I simply can't understand it no matter how hard I try

**Important Notes:**

- It should match after OR before (not both), or we will end with
  "this,is,,a,test"
- There are no spaces between commas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something less *flaky* than a regex for this sort of replacement?

```
str = str
     .split(',')
     .filter(function(token) { return token !== 'unwanted' })
     .join(',');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcx3E/).

However if you are convinced a regex is the best way...

```
str = str.replace(/(^|,)?unwanted(,|$)?/g, function(all, leading, trailing) {
    return leading && trailing ? ',' : '';
});
```

(thanks [Logan F. Smyth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8571061/31671).)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pg587/).

Comment: that seems quite interesting, I will give it a try

Comment: the first function fails with ",unwanted,..." (I end up with ",...")

Comment: @TuxedoKnightChess: I don't believe it does, check the fiddle.

Comment: Capturing parentheses are not necessary for `(,)?` (and may just add overhead) -- simply using `,?` should work.

Comment: @bobbymcr: How would I then refer to them in my function?

Comment: The regex doesn't work for strings like "zzzunwanted,zunwantedz,etc" (I deleted my answer because it had the same problem). I quite like your filter version, noting of course that [IE < 9 doesn't implement filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: @nnnnnn: Thanks, I forgot to test for that. I'll try and fix that :)

Comment: @alex This should work. `str.replace(/(^|,)unwanted(,|$)/g, function(a, l, t) { return l && t ? ',' : ''; })`

Comment: @LoganF.Smyth: Sorry, forgot to update this. I've updated it now, attributed the source and upvoted yours :)

Answer (score 1):

Since Alex hasn't fixed this in his solution, I wanted to get a fully functional version up somewhere.

```
var unwanted = 'unwanted';
var regex = new RegExp('(^|,)' + unwanted + '(,|$)', 'g');
str = str.replace(regex, function(a, pre, suf) {
  return pre && suf ? ',' : '';
});
```

The only thing to be careful of when dynamically building a regex, is that the 'unwanted' variable can't have anything in it that could be interpretted as a regex pattern.

There are way easier ways to parse this though, as Alex mentioned. Don't resort to regular expressions unless you have to.

Comment: In general I prefer regex solutions for this type of thing, but you didn't allow for strings like `"unwantedzzz,test,unwanted,zzzunwanted,etc"`.

Comment: @nnnnnn it works with ",ex,|ex,|,ex". By the way, do you know how to make: a)search for a var and b)make a global search. I tried with http://jsfiddle.net/Pg587/1/

Comment: @TuxedoKnightChess I edited my answer to use a better solution, like what Alex had, but to also account for the unwanted string being in part of a word. It also does a global search and replaces dynamically. Just remember you will need to escape any characters other than standard word characters.